# how to read from multiple txt files and remove duplicates, in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to read multiple txt files in R to create a unique dataframe.

Example:
df1 (sample1)

| row.names | count |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 |
| name2 | 0 |
| name3 | 1 |

df2 (sample2)

| row.names | count |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 |
| name2 | 0 |
| name4 | 1 |

I would like to obtain a dataframe that contains all the rownames (without duplicates) and the column "count" from each sample (df1 and df2):

| row.names | sample1 | sample2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 1 | 1 |
| name2 | 0 | 0 |
| name3 | 1 | 0 |
| name4 | 0 | 1 |

I tried multiple approaches to solve this problema but I always got stuck at some point.

Comment: dplyr::full_join(df1, df2) ?

Comment: The function works but I can't manage to make it work on  all the data frames in my environment.